# Animate Element on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, uikit

I want to animate something after the entire page loads. I'm using jQuery and UI Kit right now.

So far I have:

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
    UIkit.scrollspy('menus','cls:uk-animation-slide-top');
});
```

Comment: How is this working for you so far?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've played around and I got it to do what I want however the animation acts a little differently. Here's what I've got:

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
    $('#loading').fadeOut(500); // Hide loading screen
    UIkit.scrollspy('.menus',{cls:'uk-animation-slide-top',delay:500}); // Animate top menus
});
```

So when the page fully loads, the loading screen disappears and then the element animates. Perfect!

However, the element is a div tag containing two navbars. For some reason when I animate it this way it sticks them both to the very top instead of one on top of the other. You can see it at http://culturehog.com. I don't know why animating it this way would affect the sticky; when I add the animation directly to the element it loads fine.